# C++ weird error with variable not being declared in scope, when it clearly is

Tags: c++, scope

I'm currently trying use a very simple check using the variable "breakOK", in order to break out of a for loop. If the condition that the current value in my puzzle matrix is set to 46 is satisfied, a function is called and breakOK is set to 1 so that we can break out of the loop. However I get the following errors where I use breakOK in the if statements of the code below:

```
sudoku.cc:482:13: error: 'breakOK' was not declared in this scope

sudoku.cc:485:11: error: 'breakOK' was not declared in this scope
```

This is really weird because I declare Guess in the same manner and I do not get a scope error when using it at a later time in my code! Also, the compiler doesn't complain when I set breakOK equal to 1 in the loop. Any help would be much appreciated, I've been stuck on this for too long!

```
int Guess = 0; // will be set to a value if a guess is ok

int breakOk = 0; // will be set to 1 if breaking out of loops is necessary

for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++)
{
  for (int col = 0; col < 9; col++)
  {
    if (puzzle.matrix[row][col].currentValue == 46)
    {

      Guess = guessValues(row, col, puzzle, tried, allowed);
      breakOk = 1;

    }
    if (Guess != 0)
    {
      tried[row][col].tries.push_back(Guess);
      //puzzle.decide(row, col, Guess);
      puzzle.matrix[row][col].currentValue = Guess;
    }
    if (breakOK == 1) // line 482
      break;
  }
  if (breakOK == 1) // line 485
    break;
}
```

Comment: Can you point out which lines are 485 and 482?

Comment: check your breakOK variable name.. they look different.

Comment: You need to follow the naming-convention of the language carefully.

Comment: It's just a typo. Personally, I think this question could be useful to some people who search the error and happen to have the same problem. *What* has the typo is irrelevant.

Answer (score 4):

You declare `breakOk`, but check `breakOK`. Notice the capital K in OK.

Comment: haha holy crap, that was dumb. Thanks so much!

Comment: @user1522316, It's happened to me many a time. It's all part of learning to check for typos when that error comes up, and that, which goes beyond this specific case alone, is the heart of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's because your variable is breakOk and you are referencing breakOK

Answer (score 2):

`breakOK` is not the same as `breakOk`. Check your case on the `k`.